# A great halloween combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

A spider has one shoe and one sock for each of its eight legs. In how many different orders can the spider put on its socks and shoes, assuming that the sock must be put on before the shoe? (Each shoe/sock corresponds with one leg).
I have simplified the problem to one involving Catalan numbers while rearranging parentheses, and my answer is 14. However, I feel that this number is a bit small, so can anyone provide verification?

Comment: $14$ is the number of ways that you can have four open and four close parentheses.  Even if all you care about is whether it was a sock or a shoe that he puts on next and not caring about the location, you have *eight* socks and *eight* shoes to put on.  I however strongly suspect that the specific legs that the socks and shoes are placed matter.

Comment: So would it be $(14 \times 8!)$?

Comment: No. $~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: I'm deleting the tag "Catalan numbers" since the connection of Catalan numbers to this problem is unexplained.  In the nested parentheses problem, each close parenthesis matches the most recent open parenthesis, but in the sock/shoe problem, each shoe could match any of the previous socks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let each leg of the spider be represented by one of the letters $a,b,c,\dots,h$.

What useful interpretation might we use for an arrangement of the string `aabbcc...hh`?

> As discussed in comments below, given a sequence of putting on socks and shoes for the spider, we can write it down based on which leg received a new article of clothing at what time.  The first occurrence of a letter corresponds to the respective leg receiving a sock and the second occurrence corresponds to the leg receiving a shoe.  We recognize then that there is a bijection between our problem and the problem of counting arrangements of the string `aabbcc...hh`.

Comment: Is this not just simple choosing? Just calculate the number of different positions and then divide by the number of repetitions?

Comment: @GerardL. You did not answer my leading question and went off on a tangent.  Before we should even discuss the question of counting the number of arrangements of `aabb...hh`, you should first understand *why* I would bring this up in the first place.  What does the problem of arranging `aabb...hh` have anything to do with spiders and socks and shoes?

Comment: Well, the first letter would be the sock and the second would be the shoe. There are eight letters for the eight legs, and the rearrangement of the letters would be the number of ways to put everything on.

Comment: That is correct.  Now, for counting the number of ways to rearrange `aabb...hh`, this should be a classic problem with solution explainable by [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) or however else you prefer to describe it.

Comment: Couldn't I just do it by doing choice by choice?

Comment: "*...or however else you prefer to describe it.*" Yes you can.

Comment: Would the answer be 12870?

Comment: No, and I don't see where that number could have possibly come from.  Instead of guessing a number and writing it without explanation, include your calculations.  What formula did you try to use and why?  I gave you a wiki link to multinomial coefficients before which if you were to read and understand would give a very quick and easy to follow formula to use.

Comment: I don't see how I can express this as a sum of two numbers to a product.

Comment: Have you seen the question of how many ways you can rearrange the letters in the word `MISSISSIPPI`?  It is included as an example in the wiki link I gave earlier.  It can be done in $\frac{11!}{1!4!4!2!}$ ways.  $11$ because that is the number of letters total in the word `MISSISSIPPI`, $1$ because that is the number of M's, and then 4 I's, 4S's and 2 P's.  Now, back to our problem, we are again trying to count the number of arrangements of the word `aabbcc...hh`.  How many letters total?  How many of each letter respectively?  What do we do with this information?

Comment: 16 total letters, 2 of each. So we would do 16! divided by 2^8.